# squid : faster internet but not responsive

Tags: linux, squid, cache, optimization, web

I configured my gateway server with squid proxy for my LAN, everything work normally, the browsing maybe faster because of the cache.

but it seems not as responsive as without squid, because when browsing without squid page  loading normally loaded in progressive way (image popup one by one, etc..) but under squid, we see browser is "waiting for abcd.com.." for couple of seconds,then the complete page popup.

is there a way to change is behavior, so that page loading is not presented completely after couple of seconds, but in progressive manner so it seems responsive to users?

Comment: can you proivde the squid configuration, you have used

Comment: The config will help. One issue is to check that browser caching is not getting broken.  I have seen deployments where squid alters the headers so that the browser no longer caches as expected.  When this happens your experience may be worse than no cache at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is your squid proxy using the same DNS servers as the workstation you are using to compare this with?  If DNS queries are slower from the squid box then this may present this sort of behaviour.

If you are using transparent proxy this is twice as important, as both your workstation and squid will be making DNS requests.

Comment: Using squid host as the local caching DNS server is also a good idea.